# Receiving udp packets using socket in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

Receiving udp packets using socket in c#. Source address 192.168.1.1 port-9050 , Destination address 192.168.255.255 port-9050. Please help me.

What I've tried:

```
byte[] data;
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                         SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint end = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
sock.Bind(end);
sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
```

I see the data being sent in Wireshark, but an error occurs on the `sock.ReceiveFrom` call.

I've tried with udpclient also not received any thing.
I want to receive broadcast data from 9050  port.  Please anyone help me.

Comment: A question should be welcomed. What have you tried ?

Comment: Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint end = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,9050);
sock.Bind(end);
sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);

Comment: @user3075085 you should really update the question with the example code...

Comment: In addition from what you've tried, it would be helpful to know which issue you run into with that particular code.

Comment: Wireshark shows data but my application is not receiving anything.

Comment: For instance, do any of those system calls return any error or exception?

Comment: error at receive from. if i use udp client no error but not receiving anything

Comment: Oh gawd, so you get an exception.  Great.  What is the exception message?